# Scrapy import error with cmdline

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping

I recently pip installed Scrapy and received this error when I used *import scrapy* and *from scrapy.cmdline import execute*. How does python look for these modules, and how would I go about solving this problem? Thanks!

```
>>> import scrapy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\scrapy.py", line 3, in <module>
    from scrapy.cmdline import execute
ImportError: No module named cmdline
```

Comment: Try reinstalling scrapy from scratch: `pip uninstall scrapy`, than `pip install scrapy`.

Comment: @alecxe Okay. It now throws a "C:\Python27\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 'scrapy'" error when i run "$python scrapy"

Comment: Did you named you script `scrapy.py` ? Then you are importing your script in place of scrapy from library. Rename your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be a problem with pip. Easy install works for scrapy.